# Trying to parse JSON from Runescape API

Tags: json, getjson

Example URLS: 
http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/category.json?category=9

https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/info.json

The JSON found at these URLS when copy-pasted into a validator proves they're valid JSON, yet if I paste the URL itself the validator returns this message:

INVALID JSON (RFC 4627)
Error:Invalid media type, expecting application/json.[Code 28, Structure 0]
Error:Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the problem with your code. While we are at it: where is your code?

Comment: Here's the code if it helps (sorry idk how to format this) $.getJSON("https://secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/info.json", function(data) {
 $('.runedate').html(data.lastConfigUpdateRuneday);
})

Comment: @DavidZhang Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41789333/edit) link below your question to add information.

Comment: you forgot the " at the end of the link... strings must be encosed between two "", like "secure.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/info.json&qu‌​ot"